# How to send messages not to all subscribers of channel

Tags: javascript, ruby, publish-subscribe, faye

Is there a way to send message to **N** random subscribers on channel, not to all subscribers, using Faye and Ruby client from server and/or javascript from browser. I'm interested in clients examples in both these programming lnaguages if this is possible.

Comment: Main idea - sending messages using ID's of clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found answer from creator of faye
http://groups.google.com/group/faye-users/browse_thread/thread/6cabf09bb9367e04

"Faye does not support this (send a message to only one, specific client), you can only address messages to channels. An easy way to do this is to have the client pick a unique channel using a GUID generator and have it communicate that to the server."

Comment: I'm not agree with you that `Faye` can not do that , of course `faye` can do it . have a look at this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-faye-as-a-real-time-push-server-in-rails--net-22600